# Changing Font Size when Using Arev

Tags: fontsize

First of all I am new here and am attempting to format this correctly. Please be patient but feel free to critique since I want to learn.

Here is my question:
I am using the font Arev but can't seem to set the size by changing the normal `\documentclass[]{}` command.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{arev}
\begin{document}

Text Sample
\end{document}
```

Edit (4/10/17):

There is something else going on here. I tested this in a new document before posting it. After posting it, I tested it without using the arev font. It seems I can't change the font size at all. I'll do some more investigation.

Further edit: It seems like I may just be running into font sizes that aren't supported. I can see changes between 10pt, 11pt, and 12pt but nothing else (I was previously testing with 8pt, 10pt, and 20pt). I looked at the Arev documentation but didn't see any specifications for the supported sizes. So my new question is:

Can I define new scaling to increase support for different font sizes or something similar to this?

Last edit: This was already answered here with extarticle. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Setting the font size as document class option works for me. What does happen if you use `\fontsize{10}{16}\selectfont` for example?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. It doesn't seem to work either. I think there must be something deeper going on here.

Answer (score 5):

The size does change but it's not that noticeable. I've added some struts to your example (thank you for providing one):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{arev}
\begin{document}

\rule{1pt}{2ex}\,\rule{1pt}{12pt}\,\rule{1pt}{11pt}\,\rule{1pt}{10pt} Text Sample
\end{document}
```

The first strut will vary according to the font size. The other three struts are fixed. Here's an enlarged version of the result:

[image: Text sample]

Now with `11pt`:

[image: Text sample]

And with `12pt`:

[image: Text sample]

It's more noticeable when switching a much larger size with `extarticle`:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{arev}
\begin{document}

\rule{1pt}{2ex}\,\rule{1pt}{12pt}\,\rule{1pt}{11pt}\,\rule{1pt}{10pt} Text Sample
\end{document}
```

[image: Text sample]

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, it definitely is not changing the size for me. I am using TeXstudio and started a new sample document to test this before posting it.

Comment: @D.Weinhold That's a bit strange. Is the PDF file definitely being updated? (Can you check the modification stamp after compiling the document?) Perhaps include a copy of the `.log` file in your question.

Comment: I added a little detail to the initial question. It seems like I was testing unsupported font sizes. Also I didn't see your note on using extarticle. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`article` and  `extarticle` offer only a specific set of fontsize options. If you want to use other size switch to one of the KOMA-classes:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=21pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{arev}
\begin{document}

Text Sample
\end{document}
```